# Kentico User Access Restriction

Tags: kentico

My site has multiple surveys open to the public. Since it's open to the public,  there's no database of users or participants. At the end, we publish a **download page** for participants to download the results. The way I've done it is: I created **a set of userid/password** for each survey.Then add the user through the **Properties > Security** tab and give it a 'Read' permission. Download page 1 is restricted to userid 1/pw1; download page 2 is restricted to userid2/pw2...

Things work well so far. However, lately, we have a couple of people that **participated in 2 or more surveys**. Those users will receive 2 or more sets of userid/pw. That's confusing for one, but more importantly, they have **problem logging in** different download pages because of the access denied error. I found out that the issue is in the cache. Once logged in as user1, they'll need to clear cache to log in as user2.

Is there a better way to handle this situation? Thanks for your input!

Comment: these surveys is some 3rd party tool, independent from  Kentico? In Kentico you have only result page per survey with user/pass ?

Comment: The survey is 3rd party tool such as SurveyMonkey. Yes, in Kentico I have one set of user/pass for each result page.

Comment: You don't want to create accounts or import users? On the result page in survey monkey you provide user/pass?  you end up in a situation when you need to have user for each possible combination, so for 3 suveys you will have 6 logins, for 4 survey 14 logins etc

Comment: Surveymonkey is only for the survey to get people's input, and not part of the result delivery. The results are Pdf and Excel files posted on the kentico Download page. The whole process is like this: [1] I open a survey in survey monkey [2] People complete the survey (and provide their name/email address) [3] I download the results in pdf or excel from survey monkey [4] I upload the pdf/excel to Kentico and link to them on the Download page [5] I send ALL participants an email including the Download page URL, and the userid/pass (the same for ALL).

Comment: Now that I see the issue, and the issue will get worse in the long run, I'll probably need to create account for each user. Managing users, especially the security and privacy part of it, is so challenging, for me at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things properly, each user should probably have their own account and use Roles so they can have multiple roles.

Now if you are just trying to do things quick and dirty, the other option is to do a custom 'hide/show' of the data based on a identification code they put in.

1. Have a table or something that links the Download access to that code.
2. Add a custom webpart that they can enter their access code, and it saves to their session.
3. Create a custom macro method to validate if the user has access to the download, or if if you want multiple downloads on a single page, modify the "WHERE" condition of the download repeater or something to leverage what ones they have access to based on their session.

Something like that.